# SQL ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables

Tags: sql, sas

Below is a hypothetical SQL query in SAS. This table contains a column of words starting with A, B, and C. I created a macro variable with those comma-separated values, and I want to generate a report that only has words where the first letter is B.

```
%let Letter=A, B, C;
proc sql;
select *
from Words
where Letter = %scan("&Letter", 2, ",");
quit;
```

For some reason, I get the following: "ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: B"

Why would the WHERE statement be looking for a column named B, instead of producing a report of all the rows that have the first letter of a word being B?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show the full log including the error message. And try SCAN() instead of %SCAN().

Comment: What are the names of the variables in your dataset?  You talk about a "column" that has "words" in it. But your code is referencing a dataset named WORDS and two variables , one named LETTER and the other named B. Show some example data and what output you want from that data.

Comment: Listen to @Tom. His wisdom serves programmers at all skill levels - *"Before using macro code to generate a program make sure you know what program you want to generate"*

Answer (score 2):

The SAS macro processor is used to generate text that is then passed onto SAS to execute as if that was the original text of the program.  You used the macro function %SCAN() to generate the text B in a position where SAS was expecting a variable name.  The error message says it could not find the variable B because you asked it to use the variable B.

Before using macro code to generate a program make sure you know what program you want to generate.  So perhaps you want to generate the statement:

```
select * from Words where Letter like "B%" ;
```

That will find all of the observations in WORDS were the variable LETTER starts with uppercase B.

To generate that from your macro variable (confusingly also named LETTER) you could use code like this:

```
select * from Words where Letter like "%scan(&letter,2,%str(,))%" ;
```

Note that your example value of LETTER will not actually generate what you want.  Instead if will generate this code:

```
select * from Words where Letter like " B%" ;
```

which looks for values that start with a space then the uppercase B.  That is because you included a space after the comma.

It is much easier to use a delimiter other than comma when putting a list of values into a macro variable.  For example you could use `|` character.

```
%let list=A|B|C;
select * from Words where Letter like "%scan(&letter,2,|)%" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to make this work with macros, but in SQL, this would look like:

```
select w.*
from Words w
where w.word LIKE 'A%' or 
      w.word LIKE 'B%' or 
      w.word LIKE 'C%' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier ways to get this to work, but this is two ways. One modifies your current approach and another illustrates a data step approach. If you use %SCAN() it returns B, which is a variable. If you use SCAN() it returns the character "B" instead which is what you want. To use the LIKE option I add the % to the end of the string to indicate starts with B. Alternatively you could use SUBSTR() to get the first character and compare that alone.

SCAN also returns " B" so I added strip to remove the extra spaces. I think there's an option within SCAN() to remove spaces, if you wanted to remove the STRIP() function.

```
data words;
input Letter $12.;
cards;
Apple
Bananas
Pears
Bread
Buffalo
Demo
Help
Suprprise
;;;;



%let Letter=A, B, C;
proc sql;
select *
from Words
where Letter like catt(strip(scan("&letter", 2, ",")), '%');
quit;

proc print data=words;
where letter =: strip(scan("&letter", 2, ","));
run;
```